# Why can't I install bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to install bootstrap-vue to my vue project, using the command `npm install bootstrap-vue bootstrap` but I get this mysterious error.

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@4.5.7 requires a peer of @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.0.0-beta.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @vue/cli-service@4.5.7 requires a peer of @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.0.0-beta.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jsdom@15.2.1 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\roeir\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\Programming stuff\Chatting app\chat-client\node_modules\@nuxt\opencollective\node_modules\chalk
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\roeir\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\Programming stuff\Chatting app\chat-client\node_modules\@nuxt\opencollective\node_modules\chalk' -> 'C:\Users\roeir\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\Programming stuff\Chatting app\chat-client\node_modules\@nuxt\opencollective\node_modules\.chalk.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\roeir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-08T14_54_53_107Z-debug.log
```

this is my directory `C:\Users\roeir\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\Programming stuff\Chatting app\chat-client`

Comment: Try to use a path only with ascii chars

Comment: also didn't work in directory D:, `D:\chat-client`

Comment: did you checked the suggested npm error log in 
C:\Users\roeir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-08T14_54_53_107Z-debug.log ???

Comment: Yes it is the same message as the above

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
npm i bootstrap-vue
```

Had the same issue and this (found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue) solved my problem.